Add blank option to dropdown cell in closedxml
I am creating a dropdown in closedxml using c# by doing the following:
        List<string> supplyOptions = new List<string> { " ", "TRUE", "FALSE" };
        string validSupplyOptions = $"\"{string.Join(",", supplyOptions)}\"";

        string supplyColumnLetter = XLHelper.GetColumnLetterFromNumber(supplyOnlyColumnIndex);
        range = worksheet.Range($"{supplyColumnLetter}2:{supplyColumnLetter}{lastRowUsed}");
        range.CreateDataValidation().List(validSupplyOptions, true);

The issue I'm, having is that the created dropdown only has the option TRUE and FALSE, the blank option is not being made. What do I need to do in order to have a blank option as well as true and false?
